# How to fetch specific value from RabbitMq using Mule

Tags: rabbitmq, mule, amqp, mule-el, mule-module-jpa

I am reading data from salesforce via streaming API. The value I retrieved from salesforce is in the following format({Name:abcd, id:21221321}).

I like to store the above mentioned value in rabbitMQ using AMQP connector in Mule and I need to retrieve only the 'id' value from rabbitmq using Mule.

Is it possible

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the **exchanges** and **routing keys** for this purpose, e.g. create an exchange with the specific Name and utilize the id's as routing keys to direct the messages. In keeping with your example value: when your consumer binds to an exchange with abcd, it can then retrieve the message with the id 21221321.

Check out RabbitMQ's tutorial on [routing](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html) for a deeper explanation.

There's also another question that was asked a while back that dealt with a similar problem: [RabbitMQ— selectively retrieving messages from a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142071/rabbitmq-selectively-retrieving-messages-from-a-queue).