# Grails rabbitmq native filter messages to consumer

Tags: grails, groovy, rabbitmq, grails-plugin, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm using `grails 3.2.3` version and `rabbitmq native plugin 3.3.2` (http://budjb.github.io/grails-rabbitmq-native/doc/manual/). I am trying to achieve the following scenario.
[image]

**Description:** I'm sending multiple messages to a single queue with headers and On the consumer section I tried to apply binding to consume message by specific filtering. But the consumer consumes all messages regardless of filtering - means the binding is not working. Also I'm starter on rabbitmq. So any help/direction is much appreciated. Below is my code.

**Queue config in application.groovy:**

```
rabbitmq {
    queues = [
        [
                name      : "mail.queue",
                connection: "defaultConnection",
                durable   : true
        ]
]
```

}

**Sending to queue function:**

```
protected void sendToQueue(QueueType queueType, Map message, Map<String, String> binding = null) {
    rabbitMessagePublisher.send {
        routingKey = queueType.queueName
        body = message
        autoConvert = true
        if (headers != null) {
            headers = binding
        }
    }
}
```

Here on `sendToQueue` I made the third parameter optional as I won't need multiple types of consumers in some cases;

**Calling send to queue:**

```
sendToQueue(QueueType.EMAIL_QUEUE, [user: user], ["emailType": EmailType.PASSWORD_RESET.name()])
sendToQueue(QueueType.EMAIL_QUEUE, [user: user], ["emailType": EmailType.PASSWORD_RESET_SUCCESS.name()])
```

**Consumer 1:**

```
static rabbitConfig = [
        queue   : QueueType.EMAIL_QUEUE.queueName,
        binding : ["emailType": EmailType.PASSWORD_RESET.name()],
        match   : "all",
        consumer: 10
]

def handleMessage(Map message, MessageContext context) {
    print("From PasswordResetEmailConsumer consumer")
    println(message)
    passwordResetEmailService.sendPasswordResetMail(message)
}
```

**Consumer 2:**

```
static rabbitConfig = [
        queue   : QueueType.EMAIL_QUEUE.queueName,
        binding : ["emailType": EmailType.PASSWORD_RESET_SUCCESS.name()],
        match   : "all",
        consumer: 10
]

def handleMessage(Map message, MessageContext context) {
    print("From PasswordResetSuccessEmailConsumer consumer")
    println(message)
    passwordResetSuccessEmailService.sendPasswordResetSuccessMail(message)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the rabbitmq documentation I realized that it is not possible to selectively pull messages from a single queue.

> Consumer receives all messages from the queue

Although there is another option `"Exchange"` where publisher will publish message to exchange with a routing key and those messages will be delivered to the bound queues. More: [RabbitMQ Publish/Subscribe Model](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html)
The basic idea is also described here: [Stackoverflow: RabbitMQ  selectively retrieving messages from a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11142833/1342019)
Anyway, in my solution I didn't want multiple queues. So I created a single consumer and pass actual handler class bean reference with message to dispatch the message. Sharing the implementation, hope this helps someone:

**Queue config in application.groovy:**

```
rabbitmq {
    queues = [
        [
                name      : "mail.queue",
                connection: "defaultConnection",
                durable   : true
        ]
    ]
}
```

**Sending to queue function:**

```
protected void sendToQueue(Map message, QueueType queueType, Class<BaseQueueHandler> queueHandlerServiceClass) {
    message.queueHandlerServiceClass = queueHandlerServiceClass.name
    rabbitMessagePublisher.send {
        routingKey = queueType.queueName // queue name from enum: "mail.queue"
        body = message
        autoConvert = true
    }
}
```

**Handler Interface:**

```
interface BaseQueueHandler {
    void handleMessage(Map message, MessageContext context)
}
```

**Sending to queue:**

```
sendToQueue([user: user], QueueType.EMAIL_QUEUE, PasswordResetEmailService.class)
```

**Queue Consumer:**

```
class EchoEmailQueueConsumer {

    static rabbitConfig = [
            queue   : QueueType.ECHO_EMAIL_QUEUE.queueName,
            consumer: 10
    ]

    GrailsApplication grailsApplication

    def handleMessage(Map message, MessageContext context) {
        String handlerClass = message.remove("queueHandlerServiceClass")
        Class<BaseQueueHandler> handlerClassType = Class.forName(handlerClass);
        BaseQueueHandler queueService = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean(handlerClassType)
        queueService.handleMessage(message, context)
    }

}
```

**Finally Handler service which implements Handler interface:**

```
class PasswordResetEmailService implements BaseQueueHandler {

    @Override
    void handleMessage(Map message, MessageContext context) {
        println("message received in PasswordResetEmailService")
    }
}
```